# Remove border from Select2 (JS) after change event

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, onchange

I use Select2 as my drop-down list. After changing a value I get a border for some milliseconds. Maybe somebody had this problem earlier?

Select2 after changing

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the below CSS to remove it.

`outline: none;`

Actually, it's not a border, it's an [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) which is shown by `input-type` elements (like button, select, etc) when someone changes the value.